# how to get values from service into controller in Angular Js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to call a service method in a controller. Here is my code.
ROAService.js:

```
return{
loadROAValues:function(userId,roaId){
    var params=JSON.stringify({userId:userId,roaId:roaId});
    var promise = $http.post(url+'/'+'getROAItems',params).success(function(data){
        roaDetails = data;
        $log.debug("values in service class");
        $log.debug("values in ROA");
        $log.debug(roaDetails.id);
        return roaDetails
    })
    .error(function(data){
    roaDetails = 'error';
    return roaDetails;
    });
    return promise;
}
}
```

ROAController.js:

```
$scope.getROA = function(roaObj){
    var currentROA= {};
    currentROA = ROAService.loadROAValues($scope.getMemberId(),roaObj.id);
    $log.debug("values in controller");
    $log.debug(currentROA.id);

}
```

in console I am getting these values:
values in controller
undefined
values in service class
values in ROA
342
there might be race condition . how to get the values in controller.

Answer (score 2):

Your service returns a promise so you need to call THEN ...

```
currentROA = ROAService.loadROAValues($scope.getMemberId(),roaObj.id).then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}).catch(function(response) {
   console.log("failure", response);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you shouldn't do callback in a service. Return a promise instead and use `then` and do whatever you want with it in controller function.

```
return {
    loadROAValues:function(userId,roaId){
        var params=JSON.stringify({userId:userId,roaId:roaId});
        var promise = $http.post(url+'/'+'getROAItems',params);
        return promise;
    }
}
```

and then

```
currentROA = ROAService.loadROAValues($scope.getMemberId(),roaObj.id)
.then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
}, function(response) {
   console.log("error", response);
});
```